# spark partitionBy out of memory failures

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark 2.2 job written in pyspark that's trying to read in 300BT of Parquet data in a hive table, run it through a python udf, and then write it out.

The input is partitioned on about five keys and results in about 250k partitions.

I then want to write it out using the same partition scheme using the .partitionBy clause for the dataframe.

When I don't use a partitionBy clause the data writes out and the job does finish eventually.   However with the partitionBy clause I continuously see out of memory failures on the spark UI.

Upon further investigation the source parquet data is about 800MB on disk (compressed using snappy), and each node has about 50G of memory available to it.

Examining the spark UI I see that the last step before writing out is doing a sort.   I believe this sort is the cause of all my issues.

When reading in a dataframe of partitioned data, is there any way to preserve knowledge of this partitioning so spark doesn't run an unnecessary sort before writing it out?

I'm trying to avoid a shuffle step here by repartitioning that could equally result in further delays of this.

Ultimately I can rewrite to read one partition at a time, but I think that's not a good solution and that spark should already be able to handle this use case.

I'm running with about 1500 executors across 150 nodes on ec2 r3.8xlarge.

I've tried smaller executor configs and larger ones and always hit the same out of memory issues.

Comment: Can  you please add code sample and full logs

Comment: Writing out partitioned data does a sort of the records in each task before writing so it can write to one file handle at a time.  That sort isn't a shuffle as it is scoped to a single tasks data.  Is that the sort you are referring to, or do you see an extra shuffle in the execution plan?

Comment: Also, a big gotcha in Spark sizing is the memory settings in Spark don't account for memory required by your python processes.  So you need to leave a bunch of unallocated RAM on your nodes that python can use if you are using python UDFs or python RDD code.  I usually do about 1/3 of the RAM.