# Apply a function on a partitioned Parquet dataset without a shuffle

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a reasonably large (~1TB) Parquet dataset partitioned by a column `database_id`. I want to copy this dataset to a new dataset keeping only those rows where the `index` column is contained in a separate "special_indexes" table.

My current approach is:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

big_table = spark.read.parquet("path/to/partitioned/big_table.parquet")
unique_indexes_table = spark.read.parquet("path/to/unique_indexes.parquet")

out = (
    big_table
    .join(F.broadcast(unique_indexes_table), on="index")
    .write
    .save(
        path="{path/to/partitioned/big_table_2.parquet}",
        format='parquet',
        mode='overwrite',
        partitionBy="database_id")
)
```

However, this leads to a shuffle and fails with an `java.io.IOException: No space left on device` error on my 10-node cluster with each node having ~ 900MB of disk space in `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS`.

I've been trying to get this to work for days, but have not been successful. I'm contemplating rewriting this in `pyarrow` where I read the partition and perform a join one at a time, but I can't figure out why `pyspark` can't do the same thing?

I posted the SQL diagram and the query execution plan below. I'm thinking that the `Exchange` step is what is causing the problem, and I am not sure why is it necessary?!

---

[image]

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand file:/scratch/username/datapkg_output_dir/uniparc-domain-wstructure/master/remove_duplicate_matches/adjacency_matrix.parquet, false, ['database_id], Parquet, Map(path -> /scratch/username/datapkg_output_dir/uniparc-domain-wstructure/master/remove_duplicate_matches/adjacency_matrix.parquet), Overwrite, [__index_level_0__#77L, uniparc_id#70, sequence#71, database#72, interpro_name#73, interpro_id#74, domain_start#75L, domain_end#76L, domain_length#78L, structure_id#79, model_id#80, chain_id#81, pc_identity#82, alignment_length#83, mismatches#84, gap_opens#85, q_start#86, q_end#87, s_start#88, s_end#89, evalue_log10#90, bitscore#91, qseq#92, sseq#93, ... 11 more fields]
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- RepartitionByExpression [database_id#104], 200
         +- Project [__index_level_0__#77L, uniparc_id#70, sequence#71, database#72, interpro_name#73, interpro_id#74, domain_start#75L, domain_end#76L, domain_length#78L, structure_id#79, model_id#80, chain_id#81, pc_identity#82, alignment_length#83, mismatches#84, gap_opens#85, q_start#86, q_end#87, s_start#88, s_end#89, evalue_log10#90, bitscore#91, qseq#92, sseq#93, ... 11 more fields]
            +- Join Inner, (__index_level_0__#77L = __index_level_0__#222L)
               :- Relation[uniparc_id#70,sequence#71,database#72,interpro_name#73,interpro_id#74,domain_start#75L,domain_end#76L,__index_level_0__#77L,domain_length#78L,structure_id#79,model_id#80,chain_id#81,pc_identity#82,alignment_length#83,mismatches#84,gap_opens#85,q_start#86,q_end#87,s_start#88,s_end#89,evalue_log10#90,bitscore#91,qseq#92,sseq#93,... 11 more fields] parquet
               +- ResolvedHint (broadcast)
                  +- Relation[__index_level_0__#222L] parquet

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand file:/scratch/username/datapkg_output_dir/uniparc-domain-wstructure/master/remove_duplicate_matches/adjacency_matrix.parquet, false, [database_id#104], Parquet, Map(path -> /scratch/username/datapkg_output_dir/uniparc-domain-wstructure/master/remove_duplicate_matches/adjacency_matrix.parquet), Overwrite, [__index_level_0__#77L, uniparc_id#70, sequence#71, database#72, interpro_name#73, interpro_id#74, domain_start#75L, domain_end#76L, domain_length#78L, structure_id#79, model_id#80, chain_id#81, pc_identity#82, alignment_length#83, mismatches#84, gap_opens#85, q_start#86, q_end#87, s_start#88, s_end#89, evalue_log10#90, bitscore#91, qseq#92, sseq#93, ... 11 more fields]
+- RepartitionByExpression [database_id#104], 200
   +- Project [__index_level_0__#77L, uniparc_id#70, sequence#71, database#72, interpro_name#73, interpro_id#74, domain_start#75L, domain_end#76L, domain_length#78L, structure_id#79, model_id#80, chain_id#81, pc_identity#82, alignment_length#83, mismatches#84, gap_opens#85, q_start#86, q_end#87, s_start#88, s_end#89, evalue_log10#90, bitscore#91, qseq#92, sseq#93, ... 11 more fields]
      +- Join Inner, (__index_level_0__#77L = __index_level_0__#222L)
         :- Relation[uniparc_id#70,sequence#71,database#72,interpro_name#73,interpro_id#74,domain_start#75L,domain_end#76L,__index_level_0__#77L,domain_length#78L,structure_id#79,model_id#80,chain_id#81,pc_identity#82,alignment_length#83,mismatches#84,gap_opens#85,q_start#86,q_end#87,s_start#88,s_end#89,evalue_log10#90,bitscore#91,qseq#92,sseq#93,... 11 more fields] parquet
         +- ResolvedHint (broadcast)
            +- Relation[__index_level_0__#222L] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand file:/scratch/username/datapkg_output_dir/uniparc-domain-wstructure/master/remove_duplicate_matches/adjacency_matrix.parquet, false, [database_id#104], Parquet, Map(path -> /scratch/username/datapkg_output_dir/uniparc-domain-wstructure/master/remove_duplicate_matches/adjacency_matrix.parquet), Overwrite, [__index_level_0__#77L, uniparc_id#70, sequence#71, database#72, interpro_name#73, interpro_id#74, domain_start#75L, domain_end#76L, domain_length#78L, structure_id#79, model_id#80, chain_id#81, pc_identity#82, alignment_length#83, mismatches#84, gap_opens#85, q_start#86, q_end#87, s_start#88, s_end#89, evalue_log10#90, bitscore#91, qseq#92, sseq#93, ... 11 more fields]
+- RepartitionByExpression [database_id#104], 200
   +- Project [__index_level_0__#77L, uniparc_id#70, sequence#71, database#72, interpro_name#73, interpro_id#74, domain_start#75L, domain_end#76L, domain_length#78L, structure_id#79, model_id#80, chain_id#81, pc_identity#82, alignment_length#83, mismatches#84, gap_opens#85, q_start#86, q_end#87, s_start#88, s_end#89, evalue_log10#90, bitscore#91, qseq#92, sseq#93, ... 11 more fields]
      +- Join Inner, (__index_level_0__#77L = __index_level_0__#222L)
         :- Filter isnotnull(__index_level_0__#77L)
         :  +- Relation[uniparc_id#70,sequence#71,database#72,interpro_name#73,interpro_id#74,domain_start#75L,domain_end#76L,__index_level_0__#77L,domain_length#78L,structure_id#79,model_id#80,chain_id#81,pc_identity#82,alignment_length#83,mismatches#84,gap_opens#85,q_start#86,q_end#87,s_start#88,s_end#89,evalue_log10#90,bitscore#91,qseq#92,sseq#93,... 11 more fields] parquet
         +- ResolvedHint (broadcast)
            +- Filter isnotnull(__index_level_0__#222L)
               +- Relation[__index_level_0__#222L] parquet

== Physical Plan ==
Execute InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand file:/scratch/username/datapkg_output_dir/uniparc-domain-wstructure/master/remove_duplicate_matches/adjacency_matrix.parquet, false, [database_id#104], Parquet, Map(path -> /scratch/username/datapkg_output_dir/uniparc-domain-wstructure/master/remove_duplicate_matches/adjacency_matrix.parquet), Overwrite, [__index_level_0__#77L, uniparc_id#70, sequence#71, database#72, interpro_name#73, interpro_id#74, domain_start#75L, domain_end#76L, domain_length#78L, structure_id#79, model_id#80, chain_id#81, pc_identity#82, alignment_length#83, mismatches#84, gap_opens#85, q_start#86, q_end#87, s_start#88, s_end#89, evalue_log10#90, bitscore#91, qseq#92, sseq#93, ... 11 more fields]
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(database_id#104, 200)
   +- *(2) Project [__index_level_0__#77L, uniparc_id#70, sequence#71, database#72, interpro_name#73, interpro_id#74, domain_start#75L, domain_end#76L, domain_length#78L, structure_id#79, model_id#80, chain_id#81, pc_identity#82, alignment_length#83, mismatches#84, gap_opens#85, q_start#86, q_end#87, s_start#88, s_end#89, evalue_log10#90, bitscore#91, qseq#92, sseq#93, ... 11 more fields]
      +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [__index_level_0__#77L], [__index_level_0__#222L], Inner, BuildRight
         :- *(2) Project [uniparc_id#70, sequence#71, database#72, interpro_name#73, interpro_id#74, domain_start#75L, domain_end#76L, __index_level_0__#77L, domain_length#78L, structure_id#79, model_id#80, chain_id#81, pc_identity#82, alignment_length#83, mismatches#84, gap_opens#85, q_start#86, q_end#87, s_start#88, s_end#89, evalue_log10#90, bitscore#91, qseq#92, sseq#93, ... 11 more fields]
         :  +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(__index_level_0__#77L)
         :     +- *(2) FileScan parquet [uniparc_id#70,sequence#71,database#72,interpro_name#73,interpro_id#74,domain_start#75L,domain_end#76L,__index_level_0__#77L,domain_length#78L,structure_id#79,model_id#80,chain_id#81,pc_identity#82,alignment_length#83,mismatches#84,gap_opens#85,q_start#86,q_end#87,s_start#88,s_end#89,evalue_log10#90,bitscore#91,qseq#92,sseq#93,... 11 more fields] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/scratch/username/datapkg_output_dir/uniparc-domain-wstructure/v0.1/contru..., PartitionCount: 1373, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(__index_level_0__)], ReadSchema: struct
```

Comment: Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070591/2063031

Comment: Is it the `partitionBy=database_id` in the save command?

Comment: Yeah, but since the input data is partitioned by the same column, I would not expect it not to make a difference?

Comment: I thought this is probably the case, but I don't think spark "knows" this info. If you try without partition for testing, is the shuffling still happens?

Comment: Otherwise, you can probably just run on each input parquet file individually. Then there is no problem if it shuffles, because you should have enough space. Of course it is slower, but also it does eventually complete instead of error.

Comment: Yeah, right now I'm also thinking that I have to loop over all the partition folders manually... I just thought that Spark was more high-level than that. Thanks!